# Не отображаются компоненты при запуске

Tags: java, swing

Я пишу графический калькулятор на Java и столкнулся с проблемой: при запуске калькулятора все компоненты интерфейса не отображаются, но если изменить размер окна (буквально чуть-чуть) все компоненты появляются. Хотелось бы узнать как это пофиксить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculator {
   JFrame frame;
   long firstValue;
   long secondValue;
   long result;
   String operation;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.start();
}

public void start() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(250, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JTextArea display = new JTextArea();
    JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton buttonParen = new JButton("( )");
    JButton buttonChange = new JButton("+/-");
    JButton buttonRes = new JButton("C");
    JButton buttonComma = new JButton(".");
    JButton buttonBack = new JButton("<-");
    JButton buttonSum = new JButton("+");
    JButton buttonDif = new JButton("-");
    JButton buttonProd = new JButton("*");
    JButton buttonDiv = new JButton("/");
    JButton buttonTotal = new JButton("=");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, display);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
    display.setRows(3);

    panel.add(buttonRes);
    panel.add(buttonDiv);
    panel.add(buttonProd);
    panel.add(buttonBack);
    //
    panel.add(button7);
    panel.add(button8);
    panel.add(button9);
    panel.add(buttonDif);
    //
    panel.add(button4);
    panel.add(button5);
    panel.add(button6);
    panel.add(buttonSum);
    //
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);
    //
    panel.add(button0);
    panel.add(buttonComma);
    panel.add(buttonChange);
    panel.add(buttonTotal);

    button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "9");
        }
    });

    buttonRes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    buttonSum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "+";
        }
    });

    buttonDif.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "-";
        }
    });

    buttonDiv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "/";
        }
    });

    buttonProd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            firstValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            operation = "*";
        }
    });

    buttonTotal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long secondValue = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            switch(operation) {
                case "+": display.setText((firstValue + secondValue)+ ""); break;
                case "-": display.setText((firstValue - secondValue)+ ""); break;
                case "/": display.setText((firstValue / secondValue)+ ""); break;
                case "*": display.setText((firstValue * secondValue)+ ""); break;
                    default: display.setText(""); break;
            }
        }
    });

    buttonChange.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long value = Integer.valueOf(display.getText());
            display.setText(-(value)+ "");
        }
    });

    buttonBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String value = display.getText();
            display.setText(value.substring(0, value.length()-1));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть код

Comment: добавил код в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сначала отрисовываете главный фрейм, а потом добавляете к нему компоненты. Из-за этого они не видны. Попробуйте вызовете метод `frame.setVisible(true);` после добавление всех элементов.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.